# Too many connections in url openstream

Tags: java, file, url, connection

im trying here at first check, if the file on URL exists and then if it exists download it. But it throws me

*Exception in thread "main" sun.net.ftp.FtpProtocolException: Welcome message: 421 Too many connections (2) from this IP*

If i know, i always close the connection, but anyway it crashes

```
private boolean exists(String URLName) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    boolean result = false;
        URL url = new URL(URLName);
        input = url.openStream();
        input.close();
        result = true;  
    return result;
}

private void downloadTheFile(String path, String name) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    input.close();
    input = new URL(path).openStream();
    try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(name + ".pdf");
        byte buf[] = new byte[4096];
        for (int n = input.read(buf); n > 0; n = input.read(buf)) {
            out.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
    } finally {
        out.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

could anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you tell me how you're calling `downloadTheFile(`? In a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server sees that you are creating too many distinct connections, and immediately boots you off. Don't create a separate connection for each file.

While I can't tell how exactly you're calling the download function, look into using a persistent connection via [Apache Commons::net](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/).

Comment: @MarekKozlovský Seems like a coincidence, but try more tests and/or reusing connections via apache commons or your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the exists() method. The download method will fail if the file doesn't exist. That alone will cut your connnections in half.